# write script to trigger the jenkins job one by one

Tags: shell, jenkins, round-robin

I have one Job - **Job1** which generates seven files.

`- file1,file2... file 7`

Job1 should sequentially trigger the Job 2 by passing the created file's as **Job2's** parameters

e.g:

**run 1**: job 2 with file 1 as its parameter
**run 2**: job 2 with file 2 as its parameter....

Now I want to write a scheduler job which can trigger the test job.

e.g suppose if job 2 with parameter file 1 trigger's the test job then next trigger must be with other file as a parameter and file 1 should be trigger the test job in the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Believe Parametrized trigger pluging does exactly what you are looking for

[Jekins Parametrized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

[image]

Note: File pattern looks for absolute path and you might have to generated your property files inside workspace and later delete them after triggering the downstream jobs.